# WCF: Multiple optional parameters in UriTemplate

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, uritemplate, webget

The UriTemplate of my Service looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/intend/{intend}/email/{email}")]
```

The function looks like this:

```
public User LoginUser(string authorizationCode, string userId, string intend, string email)
```

My usual call looks like this:

http://localhost:60522/MyService.svc/json/LoginUser/authorizationCode/111222333/userId/0006435cec5aa5640639b5d08314bb989a43519/intend/yyy/email/abc@web.de

My next task is to make the intend and email parameter optional.

So my call has to work in all of these variants:

http://localhost:60522/MyService.svc/json/LoginUser/authorizationCode/111222333/userId/0006435cec5aa5640639b5d08314bb989a43519/intend/yyy/email/abc@web.de

http://localhost:60522/MyService.svc/json/LoginUser/authorizationCode/111222333/userId/0006435cec5aa5640639b5d08314bb989a43519/intend/yyy

http://localhost:60522/MyService.svc/json/LoginUser/authorizationCode/111222333/userId/0006435cec5aa5640639b5d08314bb989a43519/email/abc@web.de

http://localhost:60522/MyService.svc/json/LoginUser/authorizationCode/111222333/userId/0006435cec5aa5640639b5d08314bb989a43519

How do I edit my template and function to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default values of intend and email to null, as shown below:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/intend/{intend=null}/{email=null}")]
         string LoginUser(string authorizationCode, string userId, string intend, string email);
```

We can access this service via the URI below:

http://localhost:8000/LoginUser/authorizationCode/Test/userId/Test/intend/

http://localhost:8000/LoginUser/authorizationCode/Test/userId/Test/intend/int/

http://localhost:8000/LoginUser/authorizationCode/Test/userId/Test/intend/int/ema/

In this scenario, if you want to set email, you must set the intend.

So I think the best way is to write an interface for them separately like below:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/intend/{intend}/email/{email}")]
         string LoginUser1(string authorizationCode, string userId, string intend, string email);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/intend/{intend}/")]
        string LoginUser2(string authorizationCode, string userId, string intend);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/email/{email}")]
        string LoginUser3(string authorizationCode, string userId, string email);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LoginUser/authorizationCode/{authorizationCode}/userId/{userId}/")]
        string LoginUser4(string authorizationCode, string userId);
```

Different interfaces will be requested for different URIS;